# How to test a simple setter method

Tags: android, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

the class i want to test is posted below in the code section. I am trying to test the "setSubscriberName" method.
the test I coded is posted below in the testing section. but at run time the test fails

please let me know how to test that setter method correctly

**code**

```
public class ListViewModel {

private String mSubscriberName = null;

public ListViewModel(String subscriberName) {
    mSubscriberName = subscriberName;
}

public void setSubscriberName(String name) {
    mSubscriberName = name;
}

}
```

**testing**:

```
public class ListViewModelTest {

@Mock
private ListViewModel mListViewModel = null;
@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mListViewModel = new ListViewModel("");
}

public void setSubscriberName(String str) {
    String mSubscriberName = null;
    mSubscriberName = str;
}
@Test
public void setSubscriberNameTest() throws Exception {
    ListViewModel spyListView = spy(mListViewModel);

    verify(spyListView).setSubscriberName("abc");
}

}
```

Comment: you never call the method setSubscriberName after the call verify, however I don't know if is good idea write test for set methods, maybe you can see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M for more information

Comment: Please show failure message